# Confusion matrix for multi-class classification, how to get FN TP TN FP

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

Building a classifier for a multi-class classification and can't figure out how to get FN TP TN FP such to get sensitivity and specificity values. Here is my output and code.[code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v0he.png)

I am trying to get the sensitivity and specificity using a confusion matrix for a multi-class classification and can't figure out how to derive FN TP TN FP as the output for my confusion matrix is a 5x5 array.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into the question and formatted for readability. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.